# Convert JSON into XLSX of all .json files in directory

Tags: python, json, excel, file, export-to-excel

Faced with the problem of reading all json files which are located in the same directory as the executable file of the program, selecting certain elements in these files and saving them in one Excel file.

For example, I have a lot of JSON files like:

**First file**

```json
{"General":{"Code":"AAIC-PB","Type":"Preferred Share","Name":"Arlington Asset Investment Corp"}, "Highlights":{"MarketCapitalization":211528800,"MarketCapitalizationMln":211.5288}}
```

**Second file**

```json
{"General":{"Code":"A","Type":"Common Stock","Name":"Agilent Technologies"}, "Highlights":{"MarketCapitalization":567456,"MarketCapitalizationMln":222.567}}
```

I wanna take specific key and its' value and put it into excel. For example take **CODE** from **General** and **MarketCapitalization** from **Highlights** so it must be smth like this in the end:

[image]

I am new to python, so I ask for help from those who knows.
Thank you!

Comment: are each of these files one row?

Comment: @TenaciousB Yes, it is.

Comment: are all the files in one directory?

Comment: @TenaciousB Exactly. In directory with python file with code.

Comment: is csv ok instead of xlsx file? if you want xlsx you're going to have to `pip install` something like pandas

Comment: @TenaciousB Yes, .csv is ok too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you, use `glob` to find all the json files in a directory, then for each file use `json` to open those files and combine the "Highlights" and "General" keys and add all the resulting dictionaries to a list, then save to csv

```py
import csv
import json
from glob import glob

# function to open json files
def read_json(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        return json.load(file)

# function to save csv files
def write_csv(data, path):
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        # get all the keys
        fieldnames = set().union(*data)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(data)

# use glob to find all the *.json files in the folder named json_dir
json_files = glob('./json_dir/*.json')

rows = []

for json_file in json_files:
    # read the json file
    json_data = read_json(json_file)
    # combine General and Highlights into the same dictionary
    rows.append({**json_data['General'], **json_data['Highlights']})

# write the csv to json_data.csv
write_csv(rows, './json_data.csv')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It works! Thanks! And is there a way to save separate dictionaries and separate sub dictionaries? I mean, for example, only one row from General?

Comment: do you mean only one column?

Comment: Yes, for example only Code from General and MarketCapitalization from Highlights